# How to set a less class in a button list in Java

Tags: java, css, gwt, less, errai

I wanted to add a less class to a button when it has been selected.

I have a list of track buttons:

```
    @Inject
    @DataField("trackButtonList")
    @ListContainer("div")
    private ListComponent<Integer, StationTrackButton> trackButtonList;
```

When I selected one  of them I try to set the class active  to the corresponding button:

```
        trackButtonList.setSelector(b -> b.setSelected(true));
        trackButtonList.setDeselector(b -> b.setSelected(false));

        public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
           if (isSelected) {
                trackButton.classList.add("active");
           } else {
                trackButton.classList.remove("active");
           }
        }
```

I cannot set  the class "active", when one button is selected. However, if  I add the class "active" on google chrome on devTools, button gets the corresponding background color.

I have this code for this part in html:

```
    <div data-field="trackButtonList" class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
    <button data-field="trackButton" class="nav-item nav-link"></button>
</div>
```

And  in the less file:

```
&.nav-item.nav-link {
    &.active {
        background-color: @light-green-color;
    }}
```

The trackButton is injected in this way:

```
    @Inject
    @Named("button")
    @DataField("trackButton")
    private HTMLElement trackButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a minor mistake in the LESS code, it should be:

```
.nav-item.nav-link {
    &.active {
        background-color: @light-green-color;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless I don't think the problem is there. I think it's in the way you mark the component as selected. Sometimes `ListComponent.selectComponent()` doesn't work as expected if you don't use the correct component instance as parameter.

Try using `ListComponent.selectModel()` instead.